# Qt GUI: как поменять два элемента интерфейса местами?

Tags: qt

Привет. Есть одна консольная игра nethack, для нее есть несколько графических интерфейсов. Мне приглянулся qt, но в нем есть один недостаток. Взгляните на этот скриншот: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Окно игры состоит из трех основных элементов: карта (внизу), сообщения (слева сверху), статус (справа сверху). Я часто читаю окно сообщений, но расположено оно неудобно - слева, а было бы лучше, если располагалось бы в центре. Было бы неплохо поменять местами окна статуса и сообщений. Вот как я хочу сделать: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] К сожалению, я не нашел внутриигровых настроек, которые позволили бы это сделать. Все, что можно делать с этим окнами - это увеличивать или уменьшать их, перетягивая влево или вправо. Остается только редактирование исходного кода. Исходный код игры открыт, компилировать я умею. Знания Qt - почти нулевые, навыки программирования - начальные. Смог найти код, который описывает, как сделаны окна сообщений и статуса. А что редактировать - понятия не имею. Прочитал немного документацию Qt, узнал, что располагать элементы GUI можно несколькими способами, можно вручную задавать координаты, или воспользоваться компоновщиком. Я не стал дальше читать, а решил спросить здесь. Как же все таки решить эту задачу? Кто хочет взглянуть на исходный код игры, он располагается здесь https://github.com/chasonr/nethack-3.6.0-patches/tree/interfaces . В папке win располагаются папки qt и qt4.
Я также задавал этот вопрос здесь https://evileg.com/ru/forum/topic/356/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже нашел решение, нужно было поменять в qt4main.cpp:

```
    hsplitter->insertWidget(0, message->Widget());
    hsplitter->insertWidget(2, status->Widget());
```

на

```
    hsplitter->insertWidget(2, message->Widget());
    hsplitter->insertWidget(0, status->Widget());
```

Проверил твои решения, не подошли. Но тем не менее, спасибо за уделенное время! Если бы я не решил проблему раньше, то твой ответ облегчил бы мне задачу.

Comment: Эм, код же один и тот же

Comment: Действительно, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй поменять значения координат

```
void NetHackQtMainWindow::layout()
{...
    message->Widget()->setGeometry(0,0,topw,toph);
    invusage->setGeometry(topw,0,iuw,toph);
    status->Widget()->setGeometry(topw+iuw,0,topw,toph);
    map->Widget()->setGeometry(QMAX(0,(c->width()-maxs.width())/2),   
               toph,c->width(),maph);

на 
    message->Widget()->setGeometry(topw+iuw,0,topw,toph);
    invusage->setGeometry(topw,0,iuw,toph);
    status->Widget()->setGeometry(0,0,topw,toph);
```

или номер

```
void NetHackQtMainWindow::ShowIfReady()
{...
    stack->addWidget(map->Widget(), 0);
    stack->addWidget(message->Widget(), 1);
    stack->addWidget(status->Widget(), 2);
```